# Groupby and only keep cells meeting specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataset:

| Functional Loc. | Main WorkCtr |
| --- | --- |
| 1110-40-KB01A | POMMEC |
| 1110-40-KB01A | POMELE |
| 1110-42-PSV 154H | POMMEC |
| 1110-42-PSV 154H | POMMEC |
| 1110-51-PA03B | POMELE |
| 1110-51-PA03B | POMMEC |
| 1110-53-TB01B | POMMEC |
| 1110-53-TB01B | POMMEC |
| 1110-10-MC01 | POMELE |
| 1110-20-HA01A | POMMEC |

I want to groupby Column A, but only keep the groups that contains both cell values for Column B, giving me:

| Functional Loc. | Main WorkCtr |
| --- | --- |
| 1110-40-KB01A | POMMEC |
| 1110-40-KB01A | POMELE |
| 1110-51-PA03B | POMELE |
| 1110-51-PA03B | POMMEC |

I've tried the following code:

```
df2=df.groupby('Functional Loc.').apply(lambda x: x['Main WorkCtr']==('POMELE' and 'POMMEC'))
```

But this gives me boolean values, and they don't seem to be correct.

Comment: what is `Functional Loc.` anf `Main WorkCtr`

Comment: Is this really grouping not filtering instead? as it looks youre not aggregating ore sth, youre just giving out all values of columna that have both values in column b

Comment: I apologize. I forgot to change the column headers. I have now updated them.

Comment: MrIrrelevant:  I should add that in the full dataset there is multiple occurrences non-duplicate values in 'Functional Loc.'. I've added some to the sample for clerifying.

Comment: `df[df.groupby('Functional Loc.')['Main WorkCtr'].transform({'POMMEC', 'POMELE'}.issubset)]`

Answer (score 3):

You can try as follows:

```
df.groupby('Functional Loc.').filter(lambda x: set(x['Main WorkCtr']) == {'POMMEC', 'POMELE'})
```

Answer (score 2):

You were actually almost there, is not `.apply` is `.filter`:

```
df.groupby('Functional Loc.').filter(lambda x: 'POMMEC' in x['Main WorkCtr'].values and 'POMELE' in x['Main WorkCtr'].values)
```